# Sparklines inside Table in R Markdown

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown, kable

I'm using kableExtra and ultimately I want to render it as a pdf in R Markdown. In trying to add sparklines/histograms, I tried:

```
library(kableExtra)
mpg_list <- split(mtcars$mpg, row.names(mtcars))
inline_plot <- data.frame(car = row.names(mtcars), mpg = mtcars$mpg, mpg_hist = "")
inline_plot %>% 
  kbl(booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  kable_paper(full_width = FALSE) %>%
  column_spec(3, image = spec_hist(mpg_list, same_lim = FALSE))
```

This gives the following:

[image]

This is incorrect however. The orientation is not right and the histograms don't align. I want the histogram to be replaced with a rectangle that corresponds to value in mpg.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you want to see in result? Give a pic.